# What is the history of the word "addict"?

Tags: english, etymology, latin, greek

Usually the origins of the word "addict" are referred to Latin. Once I read somewhere that such word could have greek roots, from "diké", justice, rights. Something like "adiktoi" could mean "those not entitled to rights", therefore slaves. It makes some sense, at least.
Where could we find support to trust or to distrust such claims?

Comment: It has a straightforward Latin etymology, with cognates in present-day Romance language (for example [addetto](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/addetto) in Italian), so I don't really see the point in trying to find alternative etymologies. For any language, there's probably a word similar enough to this that someone could come up with a made-up etymology for... doesn't mean they should.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has a trivial etymology that can easily be researched without going for far-fetched hypotheses.

Answer (score 10):

It comes from Latin *addico*, which means, amongst other things, "to devote", so an addict is someone who is (excessively) devoted to something, from the past participle *addictus*, "devoted". You can look up the etymology of English words on [Etymology Online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=addict&allowed_in_frame=0). Note that the double *d* could never have come from Greek *adikê*, nor could the combination *-ct*.

Comment: I thought it was pretty obvious that Cerberus means that in this particular case we can't get from /k/ Greek _adikê_ to /kt/ in English _addict_ without some hand-wave-y magic.

Comment: @hippietrail: As Limetom correctly said, I wrote "[-ct] could never have come from Greek *adikê*". There are words on -ct, like dialect and cataract, though not many.

Comment: @Cerberus: Oh yes sorry I read that wrong.

Comment: I thank everyone and all kind clarifications. Now I understand that there is no etymological trend reaching greek language. Would then still exist, in classical greek, some word meaning "slave", merging "a" and "diké", describing the slave simply as someone who has been deprived from the access to rights? I just look for some historical tips to characterize "slave" as someone not entitled to ask for the protection granted by the laws. If this could be accomplished by greek history and language, or any other history-language pair, it would be still wonderful for me. Thanks again.

Comment: @Antonio: I'm afraid all compounds of *a(n)-* + *dikê* mean the opposite of justice, "wrong, unjust, evil", rather than "without rights". All words for slave that I can think of are related to *pais* "child", *domos* "house", or *doulos* "slave" (unknown prior meaning): see [Woodhouse](http://artflsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/efts/dicos/woodhouse_test.pl?keyword=^Slave,%20subs.). Note also that slaves were not the only Athenians without rights: immigrants, women, and children were not citizens either, i.e. they didn't have civil rights. Only a small minority of people were citizens, maybe 20 %.

Comment: Thank you very much, Cerberus. I'm already really convinced that "there's no exit" this way. It's wonderful the existence of such communities as linguistics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Antonio: Yeah, I'm sorry to be the bringer of great news. Welcome to the website, by the way. By the way, if my answer answered your question, you can give it a tick mark (click on the light-grey tick mark immediately under the down-vote button next to my answer).

Comment: Temple slaves, or servants, were devoted one way or another. So your explanation does not deny OP's question. Also, please be specific about what kind of Latin, as it covers millenia. The thought of looking it up myself is intimidating. If it's in the oldest layer of whitnessed material, and is thus likely older, then there's nothing to look up; at least not in etymonline

Comment: @vectory: Hmm you mean non-Indo-European words that resemble *pais* and are used in different families, and could therefore also have been the source of Greek *pais*?

Comment: @Cerberus reviewing the source I had in mind, I have to revise, and delete the comment. The correspondance is with Hurro-Urartian, which could be a loan from Old Hittite, we really don't know. There's no Semitic correspondance I'm aware of, although, since /b/ in PIE or the phonetic nature of \*p is dubious, the relation might not be obvious. It's futile, if it's true that "… this material may be derived from a root of onomatopoetic (Kindersprache) character which
might have been spread universally and cannot be studied by the normal comparative
method". Afterthought: Was *pais* satemized?

Comment: Anyhow, the two disparate meanings could be true homophones through convergence--cp e.g. PIE \*per(H)- (cf L *par*), \*peh2- "protect" (cf *pasture*) or \*pes- "foot" (viz uncertain Gr *anthrapodon* "slave")--even if, or exactly because there was "the
typologically similar semantic connection of names for “slave” and “child” in Slavic and
other languages". At any rate, I find the gloss repulsive, please excuse me; \*peh2w- "few, small" ~ "child" is well acceptable. Also, to return to my initial point: "probably originally [*synchronically*] meaning “Priest < Slave of the God”" [V.V. Ivanov]

Comment: Oh and since I do not know any Latin I missed and just happened upon L *putus* 1. "pure" < \*pewH- "pure", 2. another form of *puer*. Compare *fine*, and Ger *klein* "small" vs En *clean* (yes, they are cognate); perhaps also *purty* ~ *pretty* (I'd say ety uncertain, wiktionary says cp G *protzig*, which is in the semantic vicinity of *bragging*, *pride*, *to pride oneself*, in contrast to Ger *Pracht* "glory"). Now, this could go a long way, if purity is of the essence for archaic spiritual believes, but I don't want to overstay my welcome with purely semantical derivation. Yet: cf *parole*.